# Generic function with convertable parameters

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I want to write a generic function, that receives a list as a parameter. If the list is null it should return null.
If the list contains valid items, it should return the first item. 
The function should work with all primitive data types like int, short, float, double etc...

In my example I use int:

```
var a = new List<int>();
a.Add(3);

Foo<int, int?>(a);
Foo<int, int?>(null);

private T Foo<G, T>(List<G> list)
{
    if(list != null && list.Count > 0)
    {
        return list[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

This unfortunately does not work, because I did not find a generic constraint, that proves the compiler, that int? can be converted to int and short? to short etc...
I only want to call the function with the primitive data types and their nullable pendants and also string.

Any ideas about another solution? :-)

Edit:

It should also work with string. Otherwise Rene Vogts solution would work.

Comment: maybe `list?.FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: @GiladGreen that won't work, because the default `int` is `0`, not `null`. The list is of the non-nullable type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change the return type of the method, you only need *one* generic parameter, restricted to be a (non-nullable) value type:

```
private T? Foo<T>(List<T> list) where T : struct
{
    return list?.Count > 0 ? (T?)list[0] : null;
}
```

---

I don't think it's possible to make a single method that also can handle reference types like `string`. But for reference types you can always use LINQ''s `FirstOrDefault()` and the null-conditional operator:

```
List<string> list...
var result = list?.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That is almost what I want. But I forgot to mention, that it should also work with string (what is not primitive) I updated my question.

Comment: @DavidElsner I think that won't be possible in one generic function. Easiest option would be to create a seperate function for `string`s i.e. `private string Foo(List<string> list)`.

Comment: @StephenKennedy is correct.  Currently trying to treat a reference type and a nullable of a value type interchangably is not possible in cases like this.  C# 7.3 is updating generic constraints a bit, and C# 8 is probably going to introduce non-nullable reference types, so maybe there will be reforms for this case at some point.

Comment: Thanks :) That solution seems to be fine for me